# ubuntu on m1 virtual machine

Tags: firefox, virtualization, chromium

I installed Ubuntu on m1 UTM
ubuntu version:jammy-desktop-arm64.iso LTS
16GB ram
8core cpu
UTM virtual machine

when i tried to open Firefox it did nothing just loged me out
so i installed it threw terminal sudo apt install -y chromium-browser
now it opens but pages load half way
Ubuntu sometimes logs me out (only from ubuntu VM)

this is my first time using linux

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include details about the VM? Are you using Multipass? UTM? Something else? How much memory and storage was allocated? Which M1 is being used? With more specifics, it may be possible for someone to offer a solution.

Comment: ok i use UTM cores and ram were set to max 8 and 16GB ram i use m1 16gb ram os ventura